# I want to run a if else condition inside the react map function. How to do this?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a condition inside the card title. How do I do it? I have tried this if statement but it does output the result. Everything else is fine.

```
 this.state.projectList.map((project, index) =>(
                <Card key={index} className='mb-3' >
                <Card.Header>{project.name}{" "}
                   <Badge variant="primary">{project.tasks_count}</Badge>
                </Card.Header>
                 <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>
                           if (project.status===0) {
                               <h2>Incomplete</h2>
                              }
                      </Card.Title>
                      <Card.Text>
                          {project.description}
                     </Card.Text>
                     <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
               ))
```

Comment: 1. JavaScript inside JSX must be wrapped in braces `{}`. 2. It must be an _expression_.

Answer (score 1):

update your code like this

```
          this.state.projectList.map((project, index) =>(
                <Card key={index} className='mb-3' >
                <Card.Header>{project.name}{" "}
                   <Badge variant="primary">{project.tasks_count}</Badge>
                </Card.Header>
                 <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>
                           {project.status===0 ? <h2>Incomplete</h2> : null}
                      </Card.Title>
                      <Card.Text>
                          {project.description}
                     </Card.Text>
                     <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
               ))
```